# How to make it so that I can ask a user their birthday and calculate days alive?

Tags: c#, datetime

I have so far made this code:

```
 Console.WriteLine("Hey, what your name?");
        Console.Write("Enter your name: ");
        string YourName;




        YourName = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Wow what a nice name!");
        Console.ReadLine();


        Console.WriteLine("What about your age?");
        Console.Write("Enter your year of birth: ");
        string BirthYear;




        BirthYear = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("Enter your month of birth (number not actual month): ");
        string BirthMonth;




        BirthMonth = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("Enter you day of birth: ");
        string BirthDate;
        BirthDate = Console.ReadLine();




        DateTime myBirthAge = DateTime.Parse(BirthMonth + BirthDate + BirthYear);
        TimeSpan myAge = DateTime.Now.Subtract(myBirthAge);
        Console.WriteLine(myAge.TotalDays);
        Console.ReadLine();
```

I am a beginner at coding and I do not know how to make it so that when I do ask for the persons day of birth, year of birth, and month of birth, it can calculate the number of days they are alive. I tried putting the strings into the DateTime.Parse(); and other methods, but it did not work. How am I able to fix this?

Comment: Your `DateTime.Parse` part is empty. Please show this.

Comment: Quick reminder: you've said you tried something with `DateTime.Parse` but you have failed to show us what that was. What if you were just one single itty bitty character off from being 100% correct? Wouldn't you rather us be able to correct the code you do have?

Comment: Ah, alright I will explain that right now.

Comment: I would also recommend `DateTime.Now.Date` to ensure the current time doesn't change the answer.

Comment: Oh, alright I'll make sure of that!

Answer (score 3):

I want to preface this by saying that, given the way you're rading the date values, I would personally choose [the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69277160/3181933) by D Stanley over this answer. I'm simply providing this so that you can understand why your code was failing.

The issue with your code (`DateTime.Parse(BirthMonth + BirthDate + BirthYear);`)
is that the provided date will effectively become the following string value:

```
03011923
```

Or worse:

```
311923
```

Your system will (presumably) be expecting the date in the format `MM/dd/yyyy`, so it won't understand those values. This also wouldn't work on my system as my locale is English (UK) (and thus the default thread culture is English UK) so mine would expect `dd/MM/yyyy`.

We can improve the differing culture issue by passing a specific culture to `DateTime.Parse`. For example we can use the invariant culture, which expects dates in `MM/dd/yyyy` format:

```
DateTime.Parse(BirthMonth + BirthDate + BirthYear, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

But then we still have the issue of how the date is formatted. You'll want to combine the constituent parts with dividers:

```
BirthMonth + "/" + BirthDate + "/" + BirthYear
```

Or better yet, use string interpolation:

```
$"{BirthMonth}/{BirthDate}/{BirthYear}"
```

Putting it all together we get:

```
DateTime myBirthAge = DateTime.Parse($"{BirthMonth}/{BirthDate}/{BirthYear}", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

[Try it online](https://rextester.com/AERHW27330)

Answer (score 2):

You can either create a date string and call `Parse`, or convert the inputs to integers and use the [`DateTime` constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime?view=net-5.0#initialization-01). I'd prefer the latter since it removes any ambiguity that is inherent in date parsing:

```
DateTime myBirthAge = new DateTime(int.Parse(BirthYear), 
                                   int.Parse(BirthMonth), 
                                   int.Parse(BirthDay));
```

Comment: Sorry, I am still a beginner so, would I have to change the strings to integers?

Comment: @KyuRiii You do with the constructor that D Stanley is using.

Comment: @KyuRiii yes - that's what `int.Parse` does.